# Spring Boot Kubernetes Config does not update the value from the config

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes

I'm trying to read configs from kubernetes and stopped updating values from the config map. I attach my configs

deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: namespace-reader
rules:
  - apiGroups: ["", "extensions", "apps"]
    resources: ["configmaps", "pods", "services", "endpoints", "secrets"]
    verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: namespace-reader-binding
  namespace: default
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: default
    apiGroup: ""
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: namespace-reader
  apiGroup: ""
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: service-with-kubernetes-config
data:
  math_max: "10"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: provider-service-with-kubernetes-config
data:
  application.yml: |-
    math:
      max: 10000
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: service-with-kubernetes-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: service-with-kubernetes
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: service-with-kubernetes
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: service-with-kubernetes
          image: lionchi/service-with-kubernetes:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          env:
            - name: MATH_MAX
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: service-with-kubernetes-config
                  key: math_max
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              port: 8080
              path: /actuator/health/liveness
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              port: 8080
              path: /actuator/health/readiness
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: discovery-service-with-kubernetes-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: discovery-service-with-kubernetes
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: discovery-service-with-kubernetes
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: discovery-service-with-kubernetes
          image: lionchi/discovery-service-with-kubernetes:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9090
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              port: 9090
              path: /actuator/health/liveness
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              port: 9090
              path: /actuator/health/readiness
---
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: service-with-kubernetes-autoscaling
spec:
  scaleTargetRef: # что конкретно автоскейлим
    apiVersion: apps/v2beta1v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: service-with-kubernetes-deployment
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 2
  metrics:
    - type: Resource
      resource:
        name: cpu
        targetAverageUtilization: 70
    - type: Resource
      resource:
        name: memory
        targetAverageUtilization: 80
---
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: discovery-service-with-kubernetes-deployment
spec:
  scaleTargetRef: # что конкретно автоскейлим
    apiVersion: apps/v2beta1v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: service-with-kubernetes-deployment
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 2
  metrics:
    - type: Resource
      resource:
        name: cpu
        targetAverageUtilization: 70
    - type: Resource
      resource:
        name: memory
        targetAverageUtilization: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: service-with-kubernetes-service
spec:
  selector: # на какие ПОДЫ будет действовать правило
    project: service-with-kubernetes
  ports:
    - name: service-with-kubernetes-listener
      protocol: TCP
      # Port on ClusterIp
      port: 8080
      # Port on POD
      targetPort: 8080
  type: ClusterIP
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: discovery-service-with-kubernetes-service
spec:
  selector: # на какие ПОДЫ будет действовать правило
    project: discovery-service-with-kubernetes
  ports:
    - name: discvovery-service-with-kubernetes-listener
      protocol: TCP
      # Port on Load Balancer
      port: 9090
      # Port on POD
      targetPort: 9090
  type: NodePort
```

bootstrap.yml

```
spring:
  cloud:
    kubernetes:
      reload:
        enabled: true
        mode: polling
        period: 5000
      config:
        enabled: true
        sources:
          - name: provider-service-with-kubernetes-config
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>ru.jpixel</groupId>
    <artifactId>service-with-kubernetes</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>service-with-kubernetes</name>
    <description>service-with-kubernetes</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <org.mapstruct.version>1.4.2.Final</org.mapstruct.version>
        <org.springframework.kubernetes>2.1.0</org.springframework.kubernetes>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-client-config</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.kubernetes}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Why are the values from the config map not updated, although initially they are read from there and the service writes to the log every 5 seconds that reload has done ?

Comment: not sure what you are running inside docker images but once you have deployed POD and after that, you update your configmap again you have to restart the POD once thn and thn values of configmap will be there in new pods.

Comment: @HarshManvar It turns out that new values are picked up on the fly is not to do this ? Do you always need to restart the pods ?

Comment: Yes you need to restart pod each time if you update value in configmap and want that value in deployment(pod)

Comment: You can also deploy and use this : https://github.com/stakater/Reloader it will auto reload deployment if any configmap changes.

Comment: @HarshManvar I'll take a good look this way. I was just reading the spring book cloud kubernetes documentation and it was supposedly possible to make a substitution on the fly, but it didn't work out for me